# Correct way to put parameters in a function

Tags: java, spring

I have a huge form with around 30 parameters and I don't think it's a good idea to do what I usually do.
 The form will be serialized and pass all the parameters via ajax post to spring controller.

I usually do like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save-state", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
void deleteEnvironment(@RequestParam("environmentName") String environmentName, @RequestParam("imageTag") String imageTag) {
    //code
}
```

but if I have 30 parameters I will have a huge parameter list in the function.

What is the usual and correct way to avoid this?

**EDIT: What if I pass the HttpServlet request only?? The request will have all the parameters and I can simple call request.getParameters("").**

Comment: Create an bean class with all of your required parameters and use that in controller method.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options I would suggest:

1. **Take an `HttpServletRequest` object and fetch needed properties separately.**

The problem is Spring's controllers are designed to eliminate such low-level API (Servlets API) calls. It's could be the right fit if a controller was *too abstract* (operates on abstract datasets), which means you wouldn't be able to define a DTO with *a fixed-length number of parameters*.

2. **Construct a DTO class with the properties needed and take it as a parameter.**

The advantage is you completely delegate low-level work to Spring and care only about your *application logic*.

Comment: I've done before with HttpServletRequest and it's easier and less code then DTO object. I think I will use that.

Comment: Please, note that with DTO it is much easier to use validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-state", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void deleteEnvironment(@RequestBody MyData data) {
    //code
}
```

Create a class containing all your form parameters and receive that on your method.

Comment: and I pass the serialize data in the ajax post normally?

Answer (score 0):

> but if I have 30 parameters I will have a huge parameter list in the
>   function.

In your request, pass a JSON object that contains these information and create its counterpart in Java.

`RequestMethod.POST` is not design to perform deletion.
Usr rather `RequestMethod.DELETE`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-state", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody
void deleteEnvironment(MyObject myObject) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: it doesnt really matter because I have a function to delete stuff

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is to serialize all parameters as Json and call back end api with one parameter.

On back-end side get that json and parse as objects.
Example:

```
` @RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "/task")
    public Task postTasks(@RequestBody String json,
                          @RequestParam(value = "sessionId", defaultValue = "-1") Long sessionId)
            throws IOException, AuthorizationException {

Task task = objectMapper.readValue(json, Task.class);
`
```

Comment: can you make a simple example? I'm not used to do this. What if I pass the HttpServlet request only?? The request will have all the parameters and I can simple call request.getParameters("").